# DailyMotion Cloud API how to get an URL with referer strict security?

Tags: php, security, iframe, streaming, dailymotion-api

I'm stuck with the DailyMotionCloud API
I need to sign a URL with security levels on it

1. geo-blocking allowing only: **France**
2. referer strict allowing only: **1 Domain** (oxygenstream.fr)

My code works but I don't know where to put the security levels when signing my URL
I'm supposed to put it in the component `[-<pub-sec-data>]` here: https://www.dmcloud.net/doc/api/api-streaming.html#signing-a-url

How am I supposed to store de referer strict URL and the Country in the `[-<pub-sec-data>]`?

**Here is the code of the CloudKey.php:** https://github.com/dailymotion/cloudkey-php/blob/master/CloudKey.php

**Here is my code:**

```
<iframe src="<?php 
require_once 'CloudKey.php';

$user_id = 'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa'; 
$api_key = 'bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb'; 
$media_id = '5466232b947399290102cdb6';
$preset_id = '54662c7c06361d307810e3b5'; // player preset 
$preset_name = 'OxygenStream'; // preset name

$seclevel = 32800 ; // I need 2 security levels (country & referer strict)
//          32800 = 1 << 5 . 1 << 15 or CLOUDKEY_SECLEVEL_COUNTRY . CLOUDKEY_SECLEVEL_REFERER_STRICT
$countries = 'cc=fr'; // I'm supposed to put it in the [-<pub-sec-data>] 
$referers = 'rf=http://www.oxygenstream.fr/vod/dmcloud';; // I'm supposed to put it in the [-<pub-sec-data>]

// We create the url 
$url = sprintf('https://api.dmcloud.net/player/embed/%s/%s/';, $user_id, $media_id);

// We sign the url 
$url = CloudKey_Helpers::sign_url($url, $api_key, $seclevel, null, null, null, $countries, $referers, null);

// We write the URL in the Iframe 
print($url . '&autoplay=1&preset=54662c7c06361d307810e3b5');?>" width="640" height="360" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Thanks in advance for helping me with this.
Hope you know how to fix my code.

I wish you a great day,

Antoine

Comment: `<br />
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught exception 'InvalidArgumentException' with message 'Invalid format for COUNTRY, should be an array of country codes.' in /home/www/0b2aa259c9df807691830fefd389c3e7/web/vod/dmcloud/CloudKey.php:464
Stack trace:
#0 /home/www/0b2aa259c9df807691830fefd389c3e7/web/vod/dmcloud/index.php(76): CloudKey_Helpers::sign_url('https://api.dmc...', '1fc52a95421f0c1...', 32800, NULL, NULL, NULL, 'cc=fr', 'rf=http://www.o...', NULL)
#1 {main}
  thrown in <b>/home/www/0b2aa259c9df807691830fefd389c3e7/web/vod/dmcloud/CloudKey.php</b> on line <b>464</b><br />`

Comment: That is caused because you are not passing an array for the country codes. The country codes array should look something like array('fr', 'be') etc... Please see my full answer if it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using the CloudKey PHP SDK you should really not have to build the URL yourself.

When using the SDK, this works for me:

```
$user_id = 'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa'; 
$api_key = 'bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb'; 
$media_id = '5466232b947399290102cdb6';
$preset_id = '54662c7c06361d307810e3b5';
$preset_name = 'OxygenStream';

$seclevel = CLOUDKEY_SECLEVEL_COUNTRY | CLOUDKEY_SECLEVEL_REFERER_STRICT ;
$countries = array('fr');
$referers = array('http://oxygenstream.fr/vod/dmcloud');

$cloudkey = new CloudKey($user_id, $api_key);
$url = $cloudkey->media->get_embed_url(array('id' => $media_id, 'seclevel' => $seclevel, 'expires' => time() + 3600, 'countries' => $countries, 'referers' => $referers));
```

Comment: If i don't want this URL to expire, I just need to remove `'expires' => time() + 3600,` right?